# Google Chart and jquery POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-visualization

I'm trying to populate a Google geochart with data returned from a jquery POST method but it's not creating the chart.  My code looks like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="geomap" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; position: relative;"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});  
    $.post('functions/functions.php', {f: 'getreferralstats'}, function(data) {     
        if (data.success) {
            console.log(data.countries);
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);
            function drawRegionsMap() {
                var chartData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ['Country', 'Hits'],
                    data.countries
                ]); 
                var options = {};   
                var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('geomap'));
                chart.draw(chartData, options);
            };
        }           
    }, "json"); 
</script>
```

The output of my countries JSON object looks like this:

```
Object {MX: "164305", AR: "120045", CO: "56741", CL: "48449", VE: "26777"…}
```

Any idea what I'm missing here.  The chart never gets rendered.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console if you do inspect element in chrome?

Comment: @Dropzilla Thats the first place I always check..no errors seen

Comment: Just looked at the documentation and your code looks good. The only thing I can think of is the DOM element doesn't exist when your code tries to access it. So this may be a timing issue. Do a test in your callback to see if the dom element exist. I would think an error would show in the console, but it may be nested. so do `var test = $("#geomap"); alert(test);` If the object does exist you should see [object] in the alert window, otherwise you will see undefined.

Comment: It may also be a callback issue where google is out of scope. If it's not a timing issue try loading google into a variable and accessing it that way. so outside your callback something like `var googleScope = google` then access your variable inside your callback, so `googleScope.setOnLoadCallback...` and for the rest etc... This is just a shot in the dark since google should be part of the "global" scope and should be accessible from withing your callback.

Comment: Hmm...this is interesting...I never see an error OR an alert for the test inside my callback...

Comment: But you do see a 200 in the network tab for your request right?

Comment: I do see a successful request for my call. I'm also hitting code just prior to the callBack but the actual callback function never gets called

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45833/discussion-between-dropzilla-and-paul)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a timing issue.  If your AJAX call returns after the `google.load` call completes, then `google.setOnLoadCallback` does nothing.  The simple solution is to start the AJAX call after the Visualization API is loaded:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart'], callback: drawRegionsMap});
function drawRegionsMap () {
    $.post('functions/functions.php', {f: 'getreferralstats'}, function(data) {
        if (data.success) {
            var chartData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Country', 'Hits'],
                data.countries
            ]);

            var options = {};

            var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('geomap'));
            chart.draw(chartData, options);
        }
    }, "json"); 
}
```

I suspect you will still have problems unless `data.countries` is an array with two elements (a country and a value, like `['Brazil', 5]`).  If `data.countries` is an array of arrays, then you want to use this instead:

```
var chartData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Country', 'Hits']].concat(data.countries));
```

Comment: That solved my intial issue and you're correct I now have an issue with adding my array of arrays.  Using your suggestion I see: Uncaught Error: Invalid row type for row 0 ... any thougts?

Comment: I just updated the output of my data.countries data...still complianing about the format for chartData

Comment: What does `data.countries` contain?

Comment: Just updated my output...it's an array with each country code as the key and count as the value

Comment: It needs to be an array with two values: country code and count, not a key => value relationship, as JSON converts `array('foo' => 'bar')` to an object `{"foo":"bar"}`, not an array `["foo","bar"]`.